# apache httpd is restarting once a day with error AH00428: Parent: child process xxxxx exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, openssl

We have Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o configuration for one of our user environment. The apache process exits once daily and restarts automatically. Things are working fine after the restart. They have applied patch(SSL). Could it be a reason for restart? IS there any compatibility issues with Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o configuration

And The apache process increases memory to 1.5G in less than a day, around 12 midnight and its releasing automatically, then some times its restarting immediately, and some times its running fine for few hours and then its restarting with exit code  3221225477 .
My doubt is how to check why its increasing memory and how to find reason for restarting?

normally error log is not reporting any error except AH00428: Parent: child process xxxxx exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.

And access log seems fine. We did not see any log messages at the time of restart in access.log
For one or two days, we have observed below errors in error.log around midnight, but apache did not restart immediately after those errors.

```
XPath error : Memory allocation failed : adding step

adding step

^
xmlXPathRunEval: last is less than zero
XPath error : Invalid expression
[Fri Sep 04 03:19:18.366953 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8676:tid 600] AH00428: Parent: child process 7876 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting


[core:error] [pid 3120:tid 5476] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 10.224.161.254:59619] AH00127: Cannot map GET /</index.jsp HTTP/1.0 to file
[Sat Sep 05 00:31:06.854780 2020] [core:error] [pid 3120:tid 5476] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters:  AH00127: Cannot map GET /%20/index.jsp HTTP/1.0 to file
```

Error.log reports something like below

```
    [Mon Sep 07 04:01:09.222200 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:09.223197 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00455: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:09.223197 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00456: Server built: Jul 10 2018 09:24:15
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:09.223197 2020] [core:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/apache'
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:09.236194 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10256
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:11.760328 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 10256:tid 452] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:12.710371 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 10256:tid 452] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:12.919224 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] settig CRYPTO ID callback: libeay32 found
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:12.919224 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] settig CRYPTO ID callback: new callback set
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:12.919224 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] mod_aipx start_handler called - begin
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:12.919224 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] mod_aipx start_handler: set path variable succeeds
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:12.919224 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] D:\\bin;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\CA\\SC\\CAWIN\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\Binn\\ManagementStudio\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\110\\DTS\\Binn\\;ent\\python-embed-amd64;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\SC\\CAM\\bin;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\SC\\IDMgrApi\\bin\\;D:\\Program Files\\Directory\\dxserver\\bin;D:\\Program Files\\Directory\\dxserver\\dxagent\\python-embed-amd64;C:\\Users\\vaimadminq\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:15.911022 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] mod_aipx start_handler: Successfully set the security credentials.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:15.911022 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] Validating SQL is available
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:15.973024 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] SQL is available
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:15.973024 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] Validating ActiveMQ is available
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:16.157035 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] ActiveMQ is available
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:16.157035 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] mod_aipx start_handler called - begin StartComponents thread 
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:16.157035 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] mod_aipx start_handler called - schedule ActiveMQStatsMonitor task 
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:16.158034 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - begin
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:16.375055 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10256:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 360 worker threads.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:17.247477 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - Security Credentials attached successfully
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:17.247477 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - Using prefix URL: xxxxxxxx:443
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:18.338533 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/sc
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:22.800542 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/sc startup successful; elapsed time 4.461 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:22.800542 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/AOM
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:25.148664 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/AOM startup successful; elapsed time 2.348 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:25.149664 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/AuditService
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:25.987706 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/AuditService startup successful; elapsed time 0.838 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:25.987706 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/DSC
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:26.428729 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/DSC startup successful; elapsed time 0.441 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:26.428729 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/Policy
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:26.658744 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/Policy startup successful; elapsed time 0.230 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:26.658744 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/resourcemgr
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:27.668792 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/resourcemgr startup successful; elapsed time 1.010 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:27.669795 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/sch
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:27.916806 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/sch startup successful; elapsed time 0.247 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:27.916806 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/StateEngine
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:28.192821 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/StateEngine startup successful; elapsed time 0.275 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:28.192821 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/alarmmanager
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:28.645843 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/alarmmanager startup successful; elapsed time 0.453 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:28.646841 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/trapreceiver
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:28.869852 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/trapreceiver startup successful; elapsed time 0.223 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:28.870852 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/aip/casesy
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:29.348875 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/aip/casesy startup successful; elapsed time 0.478 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:29.348875 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/dpm/img
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:29.784901 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/dpm/img startup successful; elapsed time 0.436 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:29.785901 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - now starting component xxxxxxxx:443/dpm/ISM
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:30.237925 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - xxxxxxxx:443/dpm/ISM startup successful; elapsed time 0.452 sec.
[Mon Sep 07 04:01:30.238924 2020] [:notice] [pid 10256:tid 2172] StartComponents - listening for component configuration changes
[Tue Sep 08 03:11:43.070281 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00428: Parent: child process 10256 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Tue Sep 08 03:11:45.208430 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH01909: localhost:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 08 03:11:45.209431 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00455: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 08 03:11:45.209431 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00456: Server built: Jul 10 2018 09:24:15
[Tue Sep 08 03:11:45.209431 2020] [core:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/apache'
[Tue Sep 08 03:11:45.221435 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10512:tid 604] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3872
```

apache httpd.conf has below configuration

```
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so


<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild      360
    MaxRequestsPerChild    0
   </IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ahssl.conf
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<IfModule http2_module>
    ProtocolsHonorOrder On
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>
TraceEnable off

LoadModule gsoap_module modules/mod_gsoap.so
```

They don't have anything scheduled at midnight, they have cron job which will run daily at 4'o clock, this cron job also restart apache every day.
Sorry for the long post. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This problem often happens in Windows because of smaller Apache’s default stack size. And it usually happens when working with php code that allocates a lot of stacks.

To solve this issue, add the following at the end of apache config file, httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

For more information refer bellow thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138269/apache-error-notice-parent-child-process-exited-with-status-3221225477-res

Comment: I tried by increasing thread stack size, but no luck it is still restarting. so I tried by updating MaxRequestsPerChild 200000. with this change apache is no restarting but I do see all the webservices handled by apache are refreshing for every 2-3 hours. is it normal behaviour?

Comment: The MaxRequestsPerChild directive sets the limit on the number of connections that an individual child server process will handle. After MaxRequestsPerChild connections, the child process will die. When this directive is set to 0,, then the process will never expire.

Comment: I spent hours trying to debug some 3rd party PHP code to figure out what php function or library was causing Apache to restart. All the while it was an "out of memory" error?!?  Why isn't one of the most common errors since the dawn of computing being output by Apache?  Ugh. Thanks, this fixed my issue.